# Generate the list of Calendar dates

Tags: mysql, outsystems

I am having a list of dates , but the requirement is to enable only the dates I have. I am using Silk UI calendar control and it has the option of giving the disabled dates. I am not sure  how to generate the list of disabled dates . I have the dates since last year., Can anyone please help me with this. I am new to outsystems  and in a real quick need. Thanks

Comment: I am not asking for code, but I am not sure how to generate the list of dates. I real new to outsystems.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understand what you are asking. Maybe you could provide a bit more context or even attach a sample that isolates what you are trying to do.

In any case I looked at the Silk UI Calendar control's documentation and here's what I found about the parameter you're referring to:

> String containing disabled days. If the string is empty, all days are active. Example: "2015-06-15, 2015-06-18, 2015-06-19, 2015-06-20"

You can find more and documentation at Silk UI's web site: https://labs.outsystems.net/silkui/

Hope it helps!

Cheers!